# (OpenCL+ OpenCV) How to use the offset of clEnqueueWriteBuffer?

Tags: c, image, opencv, buffer, opencl

[image]

The input image is imageA. I want to copy the middle 1/3 data(imageB) into the opencl buffer.

I use the clEnqueueWriteBuffer function.(I use buffer but NOT the Image)

```
    clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, 
                cl_buffer_input, // opencl buffer
                1,
                0, // NOW offset is 0
                WIDTH_IMAGE*(HEIGHT_IMAGE/3))*COLOR_IMAGE_CHANNEL*sizeof(cl_uchar),//1/3 image height
                (void*)(image_input.data), // input data
                 0, 0, NULL);
```

After that ,the buffer I copied is image C's data.

So I want to use the offset to copy image B.

The code I used is

```
  clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, 
                cl_buffer_input, // opencl buffer
                1,
                (HEIGHT_IMAGE/3))*COLOR_IMAGE_CHANNEL*sizeof(cl_uchar), // NOW offset is the offset of data
                WIDTH_IMAGE*(HEIGHT_IMAGE/3))*COLOR_IMAGE_CHANNEL*sizeof(cl_uchar),//1/3 image height
                (void*)(image_input.data), // input data
                 0, 0, NULL);
```

But the result can't be updated! Even I change the offset into 1. The result is also still.(New frame data in the video can't be upload, the result is only the first frame and the position is like image C).

So I changed the start pointer of image data, and let the offset be 0

The new code is like this:

```
  clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, 
                cl_buffer_input, // opencl buffer
                1,
                0, // NOW offset is the offset of data
                WIDTH_IMAGE*(HEIGHT_IMAGE/3))*COLOR_IMAGE_CHANNEL*sizeof(cl_uchar),//1/3 image height
                (void*)(image_input.data+(HEIGHT_IMAGE/3))*COLOR_IMAGE_CHANNEL), // input data's pointer changed
                 0, 0, NULL);
```

And... THe new result is like imageD!
It only has the offset of X line.

So...what can I do to copy just the middle 1/3 data of the image into a opencl buffer?
Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting anything weird, the results for the code you run are ok.
However, if you want to copy the part B, you need this piece of code:

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, 
            cl_buffer_input, // opencl buffer
            CL_TRUE, //Blocking?
            0, // No offset inside the buffer (the image will start at 0 inside the cl_buffer)
            WIDTH_IMAGE*(HEIGHT_IMAGE/3))*COLOR_IMAGE_CHANNEL*sizeof(cl_uchar),//Copy only 1/3 of image size
            (void*)(image_input.data+WIDTH_IMAGE*(HEIGHT_IMAGE/3))*COLOR_IMAGE_CHANNEL), // Offset the input data by 1/3 as well (the first data to copy is at 1/3 inside the array)
             0, 0, NULL);
```

In details: What you need is to copy 1/3 of the image, so the size is 1/3. The buffer offset is 0, because you don't want to write the image at the end of the buffer, but at the beggining. And the ptr where to take the data to copy has to have an offset of 1/3 of the image. So that you copy the portion of the pointer 1/3 to 2/3, into the buffer. (The buffer will have 1/3 of the original image size)